# Regex | Find 3 character length word starts with specific char '%'

Tags: javascript, regex, dart

Using **`Regex`**, I need to find a word within a encoded url query string which matches start with specific char `%` and word must be 3 chars length long including starting specific char `%`.

A sample is following:

```
Sam+JS%2C+COSP+Lepar-+Happy+Search+%28ENG%29+%5B320kbps%5D+%5B2019%5D+%7BYMB%9D
```

> *First char would always be `%`*
>
> *Second char would always be a number `[0-9]`*
>
> *Third char would be either a `number` OR an `alphabet` (either in small or caps)*

Result from above sample like be:

<kbd>%2C</kbd> <kbd>%28</kbd> <kbd>%29</kbd> <kbd>%5B</kbd> <kbd>%5D</kbd> <kbd>%5B</kbd> etc..

Hope problem is very clear.

Comment: Why not just URL-decode the string and see if it matches the right text?

Comment: @Randal I tried in JS `decodeURIComponent('the above sample value')` which throwing `Uncaught URIError: URI malformed` and 

in Dart `URI.decodeComponent('the above sample value')` which also throwing the malformed error, hence taken the second approach to replace text using `REGEX`, hope this would give you mine scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `regex` should be something like that

```
%[0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]
```

Explain the code:

```
% => matches the character %
[0-9] => matches a single character in the range between 0 and 9
[a-zA-Z0-9] => matches a single alphabet character or number between 0 and 9
```

OR You can use

```
%\d[a-zA-Z\d]  // Irn's solution
```

Explain the code:

```
% => matches the character %
\d => matches a single character in the range between 0 and 9
[a-zA-Z\d]} => matches a single alphabet character or number between 0 and 9
```

You could build and test regex on [regex101](https://regex101.com/)
[image]

Comment: Shorter is possible: `RegExp(r"%\d[a-zA-Z\d]")` (Dart syntax). The `['%']` is wrong, it matches `'` as well as `%`. Using just `[%]` would be correct, but just a long way of writing `%`. The `{1}` can be dropped, it does nothing. The `[0-9]` can be abbreviated as `\d`.